# Do I need to update a .NET Framework webapp from 4.6.x to 4.7.x or 4.8.x

Tags: .net-framework-version

I have a stable webapp application currently in production env developed using .NET 4.6.2. I tried to update the project to 4.7.2 but I received several error related to some Nuget packages used. So, for the moment, I stopped the upgrade.

My question is very basic: assuming I don't have particular requirements forcing me to upgrade the .NET version, what reasonable advantages would I have in upgrading the .NET framework?

In other words: is it advisable, suggested, a best-practice? In particular, but not only, referred to safety/security and performance of my webapp?

Comment: Microsoft never pushes you to a certain version, as long as you are on a supported version (>4.5.2). So in your case, you can keep using 4.6.2. Those errors should be quite easy to fix if you search for duplicates.

Comment: The migration guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/) might be of use. I think there were some performance enhancements in a later version, but as far as I know there’s nothing that would force you to upgrade. 4.6.2 also is supported on Win10 so it will receive security updates etc for a long time.

Comment: Thank you @LexLi. I do agree errors will not be probably so difficult to fix, but the question is still open: what about security, performance, etc.? Is it an effort that is worth facing? I don't find such info on the web

Comment: All versions are patched via Windows Update for security. Performance wide there might even be edge cases (newer versions can be slower than older). You can find most major changes in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/ but Microsoft never had a chance to document everything. If you have the luxury of time, you can carry out your own performance testing.